# Почему Files.isExecutable() возвращает true, если аргументом методу передается *.txt файл?

Tags: java

Такой код всегда возвращает `true`, почему так происходит?

```
import java.nio.file.*;

Path path = Paths.get("dir/2.txt");
Files.isExecutable(path)
```

Почему JVM считает *.txt исполняемым файлом?
(ОС win10)

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что исполняемым называется не тот файл, который `.exe`, а тот, который может быть запущен на исполнение (на просмотр контента в нём, не пример). Мы же открываем файл, чтобы прочитать. А открытие - своего рода исполнение действий/инструкций

Answer (score 0):

Потому что метод так [написан](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isExecutable(java.nio.file.Path))

> This method checks that a file exists and that this Java virtual machine has appropriate privileges to execute the file.

> Этот метод проверяет, что файл существует и что у джава-машины есть права на его запуск

Comment: А почему на linux метод работает корректно, по крайней мере, пока не поставишь файлу атрибут "исполняемый" - он выдает false?

Comment: @LazarevV. чем это противоречит тому, что я написал? Установите на текстовый файл атрибут исполняемый и тоже получите true. А в Windows для js файлов что должно возвращаться? Функция делает ровно то, что написано. И, вы удивитесь, но в Windows можно вызвать `CreateProcess` для файла с любым расширением